# Is it possible to complete all content in Snoopy's Town Tale without spending money?

Tags: snoopys-town-tale

I've noticed that certain buildings like Shermy's house, Woodstock's Nest, or Spike's Agency seem to be purchasable only with Snoopy Dollars(?), which don't seem to be the easiest things in world to come by if you aren't planning on opening your wallet.

Is there a way to purchase all content with coins, or to reliably earn Snoopy Dollars without spending real money?

<sup>There seems to be a way to watch ads for Snoopy Dollars (which appears to be broken), but I am interested primarily in gameplay methods.</sup>